# combining views of 2 adjacent cameras using rectification

Tags: opencv, image-processing, homography, image-stitching, panoramas

I have images from 2 cameras next to a football pitch and am trying to find ways of combining them.

I have tried manually selecting equivalent points along the center line and doing perspective transforms to get a top down view and by manipulating where those move to I can get a slightly squashed looking side on view. This is ok but I think there are other solutions to the problem.

I know the angle between the ways the cameras are pointing (I have their centerline vectors) and the distance between the cameras.

I have being trying to use rectification to reshape the image into something more like a panorama or other projections but all I'm getting are streaks of colour so I dont think I am setting it up correctly. How do I use centerline vectors and the distance between the cameras to do rectification.

camera setup:
[image: Example showing camera views over a pitch]

example goal image:
https://forum.actionstitch.com/uploads/default/original/1X/6079e14fb81f6737ebd5094ebe90a303301081bd.jpeg

Comment: Did you try opencv's stitching method: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html

Comment: Yes there is too little overlap for it to find points of correspondence

Comment: "stitching" consists of a few steps: finding correspondences in overlapping areas, calculating poses/alignment (also from other sensor data like accelerometer and compass), generating a projection from the poses. it's not a tunnel. each step can be executed in isolation, and each step can be swapped out for constant data. "stitching" in your situation means finding the poses once, then *applying* those (composing a panoramic projection or other projection)

Comment: you could take a schematic of the ground, then homograph each camera to it. that'll give you a stitched (without stitching) topdown view. if you're mad enough, you could dive deeper into the higher math of all of this, then extract poses from those homographies, then feed those into the opencv stitching module, to get a "panoramic" view out of that. it will have artefacts outside of the plane.